# How to get started with iRobot Roomba?

Tags: ros, roomba

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just bought Roomba 530 as a vacuum cleaner until I realise it can be used as a personal robot for hobby and learning purposes.
I have visited this page - (http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Roomba) - but the links under installation are not working.
I am an absolute newbie in programming Roomba or any robots in general.  Please point me to a step-by-step guide.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12152/how-to-get-started-with-irobot-roomba?/) by [Yeu Wen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1473/yeu-wen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jondo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22518/jondo/) on 2015-05-22**:
Anyone please fix this link by surrounding it with blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [this](http://ros.org/wiki/lse_roomba_toolbox) on how to get things set up.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2011-12-06**:
yes you are missing something :) You have to hack it. There is a mini-DIN port which allows a TTL serial connection. To that you can hook up a serial to USB or serial to wifi or serial to whatever. Google it.

**Comment by [Yeu Wen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1473/yeu-wen/) on 2011-12-06**:
My iRobot Roomba 530 is being charged for the first time for 16 hours.  In the meantime, reading the user manual from front to back does not tell me it has wifi or bluetooth or even usb port support.  Have I missed something?

**Comment by [Yeu Wen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1473/yeu-wen/) on 2011-12-04**:
That sounds great.  Thank you.
I will update back when I have attempted any or both of the above successfully or not.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2011-12-04**:
You don't modify any roomba software. You just talk to it through a serial connection. You can either do it wirelessly (XBee, Bluetooth, WiFi, etc) or like [Turtlebot](http://turtlebot.com/build/order.html), you just hook a laptop/netbook up to it via USB serial port.

**Comment by [Yeu Wen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1473/yeu-wen/) on 2011-12-04**:
Thanks, Kevin.

Obviously, I have not gone through the page in details. Can I ask if there is a utility to backup and restore the original installed software in the iRobot so that it can continue to function as a vacuum cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey:

Everyone has to start somewhere, so no worries about being a beginner!  There is a really good writeup on the roomba SCI here:

http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/3-Serial-Port-Baud-Rate-Configuration/17.html

It goes into the where the physical location of the serial connector is as well as how to send basic commands down to it. The roomba initially was just a vacuum cleaner, but irobot now has the Icreate - which is essentially the same as the roomba except no vacuum.

Are you trying to use ROS specifically?  It might be quicker to start out by using real-term and following the tutorial.  If you have any direct questions feel free to post them up here & I'll try to get back to you on them.

Best,
Ryan

---

Originally posted by [Crazyrobotman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2730/crazyrobotman/) with karma: 31 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chief_534](https://answers.ros.org/users/5677/chief_534/) on 2013-10-27**:
Thanks for posting this.  Our hand-me-down-Roomba's charging circuit just died so I wanted to start hacking it.  This will save me quite a bit of time figuring out the basics.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the Roomba 500 series drivers on a Roomba 560 robot, details can be found here -- https://github.com/Arkapravo/roomba_500_ROS_drivers

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1